# Draw borders within bars in barplot?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm drawing a simple barplot with thick bar borders:

```
par(lwd=3)
barplot(c(6,7))
arrows(0,0,10,0,lwd=1)
```

The borders stick out slightly over the x-axis, which looks bad.

Is there any way to draw the border *within* each bar, rather than around it?

Comment: Did a lot of code-inspection. I do not see any plotting parameters to rect(), polygon() or lines() that would directly support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is to hack something together by hand by setting `border = NA` in `barplot` and then adding the borders using `lines`:

```
par(lwd = 3, lend = 2)
barplot(c(6,7),border = NA)
lines(c(0.2,0.2,1.2,1.2),c(0.02,6,6,0.02))
lines(c(1.4,1.4,2.4,2.4),c(0.02,7,7,0.02))
```

[image]

This is far from ideal. The coordinates used in `lines` assume the default 0.2 space between bars and pulling the bottom up to 0.02 was just based on me eyeballing it. You might have to tinker with it on a case by case basis.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit of a hack, but it achieves the aesthetic I want. They lines are of course treated as separate objects when later edited in Illustrator, but that's not too bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion after failing to find a clip()-ping or an easy "inner border" answer is this suggestion:

```
opar <- par(lwd=3)
barplot(c(6,7))
arrows(0,0,10,0,lwd=3, col="grey")
par(opar)
```

It has the advantage that it doesn't clip the top of the higher bars. Bet you didn't notice that. I didn't notice it until I used lwd=10.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about clipping.

Comment: Look at joran's example. The higher bar's upper line is half the width of the lower one. That happens because the plotting is "clipped" at the edge of the plot region. I cannot tell you why it doesn't happen at the lower boundary of the plot region.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I saw that. Adjusting the margins and axis scales keeps it from being an issue though.